# Infinitely many or unique solution of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computational-mathematics

Consider the boundary problem
$$u''+k^2u=0 \qquad (1)\\
u(0)=u_l, u(1)=u_r \qquad\\
\text{domain } \Omega = (0,1)\qquad$$

When I discretize this problem using the Finite Element Method I get the following linear system:

$$(k^2M-K)u=b \qquad(2)$$

where the matrix $k^2M-K$ can be positive or negative definite, positive or negative semidefinite or indefinite. This means that $(2)$, depending on $k$, may have a unique solution, no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

However, the analytic solution of $(1)$ has the unique solution 
$$u(x) = \sin(k x) [u_r \csc(k) - u_l \cot(k)] + u_l \cos(k x)\qquad (3)$$
which is a unique solution. Of course $k$ may vary, but $k$ is assumed to be a constant, so when we solve $(1)$ we fix our $k$.

Yet I was told that $(1)$ is supposed to have infinitely many solutions as well. Where am I being wrong?

Comment: (1) has infinitely many solutions when the boundary values are omitted.  Or it could be the point you made that you will find infinitely many values of $k$ for which the equation has solutions.

Comment: What you have is an eigenvalue problem. Depending on whether $k^2$ is an eigenvalue of your operator $-u''$ with the given boundary conditions or not, you may have infinitely many solutions or no solution at all. As TM Gallagher pointed out, you will find infinitely many $k$ such that there are solutions (the spectrum of your operator).

Comment: The thing here is that the system $(2)$ may be positive semidefinite for some $k$ and have infinitely many solutions for this single $k$. This is not the same as picking infinitely many $k$'s for a system to have a unique solution, say, that's just for one $k$! But for one fixed $k$ the system $(1)$ always has only one unique solution, while system $(2)$ may have infinitely many or no solutions for just one fixed $k$. How is this possible?